# `MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer.nowPlayingItem` is not change state only after Music App reopen

Tags: ios, apple-musickit, ios13.4

`MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer.nowPlayingItem` is not change state only after Music App killed and reopen. 
Specifically,

1. Open Music App and play music.
2. Open created app by me. It's using `MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer.nowPlayingItem`. Confirm `nowPlayingItem` data is correct(included current playing music data).
3. Switch to Music App and kill. Then, reopen Music App and change music.
4. Switch to my app and show `nowPlayingItem` data. I want current music data, but it's old Music data.

```swift
// Run SceneDelegate when foreground that my app.
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
...
    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
        player = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer
        print(player?.nowPlayingItem?.title)
```

That's code correct ran at iOS13.3. After update to iOS13.4, not correct running.

Comment: This issue is still happen on iOS13.4.1.

Comment: I experience the same issue. My app plays a new item via `systemMusicPlayer.play()` and when I check `systemMusicPlayer.nowPlayingItem` shortly after (I subscribed to `MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification`) it's still the item from before.

Comment: Me too. Still happening on iOS 14.0.1

Comment: By the way, after some experiments I found out if you use `applicationMusicPlayer` instead of `systemMusicPlayer`, `nowPlayItem` became nil. You could possibly switch to  `applicationMusicPlayer`